# PhantomJS right mouse button click won't work with selenium webriverJS

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver, phantomjs

I'm using selenium with webdriverJS, trying to automate simple web app.
Problem is when switching from chrome to phantomJS test is not working as expected:
Right mouse button doesn't open context menu. have anyone had such problem, are there any solutions?
Here is small code sample:

```
 return driver.actions()
        .mouseMove(driver.findElement(mapping.xpath.spaceSpace), {x:120, y:120})
        .click(mapping.key.mouseRightButton)
        .perform()
```

Tried removing coordinates, adding them in click action, also different mouse events - nothing.
But same tests runs flawless in chrome, firefox and ie.

Answer (score 0):

This issue was resolved, but not yet released: https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/14005

Before it is fixed, here are some workarounds:

#### Java

```
import org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions;
import org.openqa.selenium.phantomjs.PhantomJSDriver;

public void contextClick(WebDriver driver, WebElement element) {
    if(driver instanceof PhantomJSDriver) {
        String script =
                "var element = arguments[0];" +
                "var event = document.createEvent('HTMLEvents');" +
                "event.initEvent('contextmenu', true, false);" +
                "element.dispatchEvent(event);";
        ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript(script, new Object[]{element});
    } else {
        (new Actions(driver))
                .contextClick(element)
                .build()
                .perform();
    }
}
```

#### Python

```
from selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver import WebDriver
from selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement import WebElement
from selenium.webdriver import PhantomJS, ActionChains

def context_click(driver, element):
    # type: (WebDriver, WebElement) -> ()
    if isinstance(driver, PhantomJS):
        script = "var element = arguments[0];" \
                "var event = document.createEvent('HTMLEvents');" \
                "event.initEvent('contextmenu', true, false);" \
                "element.dispatchEvent(event);"
        driver.execute_script(script, element)
    else:
        ActionChains(driver) \
            .move_to_element(element) \
            .context_click() \
            .perform()
```